# How do i store £ symbols in UTF-8 MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have all MySQL dbs, tables and cols set to `utf8_general_ci`.

If i use phpMyAdmin to put a `£` symbol into a row, when i display it on a utf-8 charset page i get the good old question-mark-diamond.

However on the same page, if i put `<?php echo 'pound symbol test: £' ?>`, the symbol displays correctly, so the problem must be with the MySQL not the page.

If i dump my database and add a `£`  using my text editor (set to UTF-8) and then re-import, same problem as with adding the £ in phpMyAdmin

[image][image]

Comment: Are you sure phpMyAdmin is using UTF-8?

Comment: I think this is the problem, if i type "Â£" into phpmyadmin it displays find on my page. Can i change phpmyadmin's settings?

Comment: The output rather implies that your data is not valid UTF-8. Otherwise the replacement character U+FFFD would not be displayed.

Comment: Please check what character encoding of the HTML document where you do the input in phpMyAdmin. I suppose it’s not UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Is your database connection UTF-8 encoded?

Try sending a query:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

after opening the connection.

Comment: Or if you aren't using an outdated PHP/MySQL version, [`mysql_set_charset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) is clearer and does effectively the same.

Comment: @BalusC yeah, depends on the database wrapper he's using (I think PDO has a native method/option to do this, too)

Comment: `SET NAMES utf8;` didn't seem to help, i opened a connection in php, queried set names, then queried an update containing £ and same problem

Comment: @BalusC - `mysql_set_charset('utf-8');` worked. I then noticed that if looked at the values it had created in phpMyAdmin, in the PMA interface, £ displayed as `Â£`. However they come out of the db as a propert `£`. My solution for fixing the db was to, **1** dump db, **2** find and replace '£' for 'Â£' in the database, **3** import back in to phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

Check [phpmyadmin wiki](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#Language_and_charset_conversion_settings)

No doubt phpmyadmin is convenient,
but I would recommend use command line
(this give yourself a chance to sharpen your sql knowledge)

Comment: I also guess that this is due to phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Victory is MINE!!

I've just sent about 30 minutes trying to figure this out, and came up with this. Possibly not the best solution, but it works!!

```
html_entity_decode(htmlentities('£250 to £1000',ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false), ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1')
```